# Как нарисовать круги

Tags: html, css

Как сделать эти точки и чтобы они находились снизу относительно текста. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На картинке они вроде и так снизу... Можно попробовать вот что: берёте свёрстанный пример - html + css, потом начинаете убирать фрагменты CSS и смотрите, когда эти точки исчезнут. Это означает, что вы только что "отрезали" фрагмент, котрый отвечает за это рисование точек

Comment: ☝️ Метод Микеланджело, к любой проблеме подходит: просто отсекаете всё лишнее.